# Dealing with commas when reading a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

There is nothing wrong in the other part. I read the lines of the excel files. But I want to split the cells of this excel. I use the statement `String []values1 = data1.split(",");` and `values1[5]=values1[5].replace('"', ' ').trim();`. But there is a particular cell which there is a `,` in it. This comma disrupts the arranged order. How should I deal with it?

```
File DopCan = new File(filesnames[0]);

try
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(DopCan);
    scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.nextLine();

    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {

        String data = scanner.nextLine();
        String []values = data.split(",");
        values[5]=values[5].replace('"', ' ').trim();
        if(Integer.parseInt(values[5])==0)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    scanner.close();

    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(DopCan);
    scanner1.nextLine();
    scanner1.nextLine();
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        ArrayList <PollingPlace> files = new ArrayList();
        while (scanner1.hasNext())
        {
            int n=0;
            String data1 = scanner1.nextLine();
            String []values1 = data1.split(","); //Problem here
            scanner1.nextLine();
            String data3=scanner1.nextLine();
            String []values3 = data3.split(",");
            values1[5]=values1[5].replace('"', ' ').trim();
            values1[7]=values1[7].replace('"', ' ').trim();
            values1[14]=values1[14].replace('"', ' ').trim();
            values3[14]=values3[14].replace('"', ' ').trim();
            files.add(new PollingPlace(Integer.parseInt(values1[5]),Integer.parseInt(values1[7]),Integer.parseInt(values1[14]),Integer.parseInt(values3[14])));

            scanner1.nextLine();
            scanner1.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a CSV, not an "excel file", then. Use OpenCSV.

Comment: my mistake, but they seem to be the same. What is the difference?

Comment: The difference is that CSVs predate Excel by a looong margin ;) Excel just has the possibility to read them, that's all (although it sucks at handling UTF-8 CSV files)

Comment: If you cannot use OpenCSV or Apache Commons CSV (two CSV parsing libraries) then you must write a better CSV parser, one that understands how to handle commas inside quoted strings.  This could be done by finding all the commas and quotes and looking at them left to right, keeping track of whether or not you're inside a quoted string.  This may be what your homework is all about.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy answer and a correct one.

Easy answer is to parse the string more robust with regexp, say,

```
(?:\s*(?:\"([^\"]*)\"|([^,]+))\s*,?)+?
```

But CSV turns out to be a rather diffucult for that as there are a number of corner cases to consider.

Correct answer is to use a library for that, and as it happens there is manifold of them: [JSefa](http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/quick-tutorial.html), [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), etc.